# R: Extract rows with NAs, delete those meeting condition A and take the mean of those meeting condition B

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, mean, na

Using the subset below, you can see that the first 8 rows have NAs in V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, and V7 whereas the remaining rows only have NAs in a few of them.

I would like to extract the rows that have NAs from V2 to V7 and delete them **(condition A)**. Whereas
for those with NAs in just a few I would take the mean of that column and replace the the NA by it in order to preserve some information **(condition B)**.

```
V1                  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
2020-12-01 09:15:00 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2020-12-01 09:20:00 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2020-12-01 09:25:00 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2020-12-01 09:30:00 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2020-12-01 09:35:00 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2020-12-01 09:40:00 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2020-12-01 09:45:00 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2020-12-01 09:50:00 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2020-12-01 17:05:00 NA  1319.48 10685.10    38.36   156.64  612.83
2020-12-01 17:30:00 12068.88    1308.61 NA  38.43   NA  NA
```

Normally, to drop all the columns with NAs, I would use:

```
dataset <- dataset[complete.cases(dataset),]
```

and to replace the NAs by the mean of the column (Vn):

```
dataset$Vn <- ifelse(is.na(dataset$Vn),
                     ave(dataset$Vn, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)),
                     dataset$Vn)
```

I'm not sure of the best way to combine the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first condition, you can usage **dplyr::filter**:

```
data <- data %>%
filter(!is.na(V2) & !is.na(v3) & ... & !is.na(V7))
```

For the second condition:

```
data <- data %>%
mutate(V2 = ifelse(is.na(V2), mean(data$V2, na.rm = T),V2),
       V3 = ifelse(is.na(V3), mean(data$V3, na.rm = T),V3),
       ...)
```

At each step, the **...** represent the same instruction for the rest of the columns.

Comment: ```data <- data %>%
filter(!is.na(V2) & !is.na(v3) & ... & !is.na(V7)) ``` ended up removing all rows containing NAs... independently if all the selected columns have it or not

Comment: Well, it was working on my version of **R**… That’s strange. Try && instead of &

Comment: That one does nothing and no error is returned... I'll keep trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We could do this more easily with `across` and `na.aggregate` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), zoo::na.aggregate))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("2020-12-01 09:15:00", "2020-12-01 09:20:00", 
"2020-12-01 09:25:00", "2020-12-01 09:30:00", "2020-12-01 09:35:00", 
"2020-12-01 09:40:00", "2020-12-01 09:45:00", "2020-12-01 09:50:00", 
"2020-12-01 17:05:00", "2020-12-01 17:30:00"), V2 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12068.88), V3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1319.48, 1308.61), V4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 10685.1, NA), V5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 38.36, 38.43), V6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 156.64, 
NA), V7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 612.83, NA)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```